# Work done by magnetic field on magnetic dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, work, potential-energy, torque

[image]

In the above slide, it reads that $W=\int\mu B sin(\theta)d\theta=\mu B cos(\theta)$.

But, I thought that $\int\mu B sin(\theta)d\theta=-\mu B cos(\theta)$ by some calculus calculation.

Can somebody explain more explicitly, please?

Comment: Whoever you are, if you are reading my question, and want to get the correct answer, Read my last four comments written in the below answer. (You have to "click" the "Show 9 more comments" next to the "add a comment" to see those comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we define the direction of $\vec{\theta}$ between $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ to be positive if $\vec{\theta}$ is coming out of the screen in the sense that $\theta$ is increasing with the right-hand-rule in the counter-clockwise direction.

Then, note that the torque $\vec{\tau}=\vec{\mu}\times\vec{B}$ makes the angle between $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ decrease in order to line $\vec{\mu}$ with $\vec{B}$. (Note that we are defining the angle $\theta$ between $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ to be the acute angle between them which results in $0\leq\theta\leq \pi/2$.) Therefore, the direction of the torque $\vec{\tau}$ on the dipole is Negative, in the sense that the direction of the torque vector $\vec{\tau}$ is the opposite direction to the angle vector $\vec{\theta}$.

Then, we choose $\theta_0=\pi/2$ to be the initial angle of the work done by the magnetic field on the dipole, in order to define $U=0$ at $\theta_0=\pi/2$.

Then, we have the work done by the magnetic field on the dipole as follows:
$W=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta}\vec{\tau}\cdot d\vec{\theta}=\int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}\vec{\tau}\cdot d\vec{\theta}=\int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}(-\tau d\theta)=\int_{\theta}^{\pi/2}\tau d\theta=\int_{\theta}^{\pi/2}\mu B\sin(\theta) d\theta=-\mu B\cos (\theta)|_{\theta}^{\pi/2}=\mu B\cos(\theta)=\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$.

Then, we have the potential energy function by the magnetic field on the dipole $U_{\mbox{magnetic field}}=-W=-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$, in the sense that the function $U$ is defined to be zero at the initial angle $\theta_0=\pi/2$ which is the angle when the magnitude of the torque $|\vec{\tau}|=|\vec{\mu}\times\vec{B}|=\mu B \sin (\theta)$ is maximum as requried in the slide.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue of not specifying the initial and final states (or whether we are calculating the work done by the magnetic torque, or the work required by an external torque to oppose the magnetic torque). In reality, what we should say is that if we start with a magnetic dipole $\vec{\mu}$ that is aligned with the magnetic field (so that $\theta=0$), WE must do work to rotate the dipole to a new angle $\theta$, by applying the torque opposite to the magnetic torque.

Let's look at the fact that zero potential energy is defined as when $\theta=\pi/2$. Then we can look at the work done by the magnetic field as it rotates from $\theta$ to $\pi/2$:
$$W=\int\tau\,d\theta=\int_{\theta}^{\pi/2}\mu B\sin\theta'\,d\theta'=-\left.\mu B\cos\theta'\right|_{\theta}^{\pi/2}=\mu B\cos\theta$$
So that's where the negative sign went.

Comment: I'm not so sure why we define that the potential energy is zero when $\theta = \pi/2$. I thought we are deriving the potential energy from the work, not the work from the potential energy. Then, how do you know the potential energy is zero at $\theta=\pi/2$ even though we haven't derived the work done by the magenetic field on the magnetic dipole?

Comment: In general, the work needs to be defined from some starting position/angle to some final position/angle:
$$W=\mu B(\cos\theta_i-\cos\theta_f)$$
Then we have $\Delta U=U_f-U_i=-W$, but we are free to choose the zero at any point we want since it's a potential energy (let's say $U=0$ when $\theta=\pi/2$). This gives the desired result, but of course you could choose any other zero point you wish.

Comment: Ok. So, we just define $U=0$ at $\theta=\pi/2$ without any reason, right? But then, why do you calculate the work done by the magnetic torque from $\theta$ to $\pi/2$ not from $\pi/2$ to $\theta$? It seems that you are calculating work done by an external force to oppose the magnetic torque, not by the magnetic torque which is opposite to the work done by an external force to oppose the magnetic torque.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to look at it is: it's the same problem with the physics vs. chemistry definitions of $W$ in the 1st Law of Thermodynamics; $\Delta U=Q\pm W$. The plus sign is used by chemists, who talk about $W$ being the work done ON the system in question, while physicists use $W$ as the work done BY the system. In this case, the system is the dipole, and the magnetic field exerts a torque ON and does work ON the dipole, so we should really use $\Delta U=+W$, in which case your calculus intuition gives you exactly what you'd expect. $U=0$ is then convention.

Comment: I think $\Delta U=+W$ is not true since if it is true, then, it would not consistent with the result above, $U=-W=-\mu\cdot B$...

Comment: Again, using $\Delta U=-W$ is assuming that $W$ is the work done BY the dipole. As the magnetic field exerts a torque on the dipole, the dipole exerts a torque back on the magnetic field (Newton's 3rd law), and it is then that torque that we should use to calculate $W$ (which is opposite in sign of the one we usually use for the torque that the field exerts on the dipole).

Comment: I don't know why you think that way, yet. But, what I was saying is that If you let $\Delta U=+W$, then when you derive the Potential energy from that work, you will get, $U(\theta)=\Delta U_{\frac{\pi}{2} \to \theta}= -\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta} \tau d\theta=\int_{\theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tau d\theta= W_{in your answer} = \mu B cos(\theta)= \vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B} \neq -\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$ Which is not consistent with our expectation! How do you think about that?

Comment: Work done ON dipole:
$$\Delta U=W_{\text{ON d}},\;\tau_{\text{ON d}}=\mu B\sin\theta,\,W_{\text{ON d}}=\int_{\theta_i}^{\theta_f}\mu B\sin\theta\,d\theta=\mu B(\cos\theta_i-\cos\theta_f)$$
If $U_i=0$ @ $\theta_i=\pi/2$ and $U_f=U$ @ $\theta_f=\theta$, then $U=-\mu B\cos\theta=-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$.

Now, for work done BY dipole:
$$\Delta U=-W_{\text{BY d}},\;\tau_{\text{BY d}}=-\mu B\sin\theta,\,W_{\text{BY d}}=-\int_{\theta_i}^{\theta_f}\mu B\sin\theta\,d\theta=\mu B(\cos\theta_f-\cos\theta_i)$$
Same assumptions on $U_{i,f}$ and $\theta_{i,f}$ also give $U=-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$.

Comment: Exactly; the slide is wrong. You can't use both $\Delta U=-W_{by}$ and $\tau_{on}=\mu B\sin\theta$. You need to pick one and stick to it. This is my last comment on the topic.

Comment: ;;;;; Slide is not wrong...;;;;; It's from smart physics which is a kind of a textbook for a elementary physics... I think you are the one who do not "pick one and stick to it"...

Comment: I think if we define the direction of $\vec{\theta}$ between $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ to be positive when the vector is coming out of the screen with the right hand rule in the counter-clockwise direction, then since the torque $\vec{\tau}=\vec{\mu}\times\vec{B}$ on the dipole tends to make $\vec{\mu}$ to line up with $\vec{B}$, (in other words, the torque makes the angle between $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{B}$ decrease) we will have $W=\int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}\vec{\tau}\cdot d\vec{\theta}=\int_{\pi/2}^{\theta}(-\tau d\theta)=\int_{\theta}^{\pi/2}\tau d\theta=$ (...continue in the next comment...)

Comment: $\int_{\theta}^{\pi/2}\mu B\sin\theta d\theta=-\left.\mu B\cos\theta\right|_{\theta}^{\pi/2}=\mu B\cos\theta$

Comment: Also, about the "ON" and "BY" things, i found that you are wrong. You said that "Again, using $\Delta U=−W$  is assuming that $W$ is the work done BY the dipole." But actually, $\Delta U=-W$ is assuming that $W$ is defined to be the work done BY a conservative force, and hence in this case, BY the Magnetic Force, (since the Magnetic Force is a conservative force) and hence, By the Magnetic Field, On the Magnetic Dipole.

Comment: $\Delta U=+W$ is used when the work is done ON "the system" which provides the external forces on the actual object (in this case, the actual object is the magnetic dipole) and thus, "the system" is "the magnetic field" or "the system who creates the magnetic field", NOT "the magnetic dipole". Therefore, your Third, Fourth, and Fifth comments are totally wrong. You should carefully examine "the system" when you calculate a work done by whatever on whatever.